# How can I search a substring on one field by using grep?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Suppose I have a csv file:

```
31,32,19,James Walker,321,James
21,31,49,Harry Bosh,282,Harry
32,12,03,Chris James,291,Chris
```

How can I use `grep`, not `awk` to search the occurrence of "James" in the fourth field?

Answer (score 3):

How you can do it is by ensuring that your regex requires three commas to occur before the main pattern, and that the pattern (which has to scan within the field) does not itself match commas, which would cause it to match into the fifth or later field:

```
grep -E '^([^,]*,){3}[^,]*James'
```

"Match from the start of the line three repetitions of zero-or-more non-commas followed by a comma. That gets us to the fourth field. In the fourth field, match zero-or-more non-commas followed by `James`."

Comment: That, `awk`, that, `awk`... :)

Answer (score -1):

What result do you want?

```
cat filename |grep "James"
```

can't meet your requirement?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above is just an example. What if I just want to grep on the specific field?

Comment: It doesn't meet the implicit requirement that if `James` occurs in another field, that that occurrence must **not** be found and reported. (If that requirement weren't understood, there would be no mention of searching the fourth field specifically.)

Comment: Also `cat file | grep pattern --> grep pattern file`.

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -P --color '(?<=,)James(?= +)' file
31,32,19,**James** Walker,321,James
grep -oP '(?<=,)James(?= +)' file 
James
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys! I finalize the operation to `cut` the file first to extract the field I want and then `grep` the string I want.
FYI:

```
cut -d -f4 name.csv | grep 'James"
```